# Get 10 rows from all tables in EF model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqpad

I found this sample from [here](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/03/01/how-to-get-data-dynamically-from-you-linq-to-sql-data-context/) :

```
NWDataContext context = new NWDataContext();

var model = context.Mapping;

//get all tables 
foreach (var mt in model.GetTables())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Getting data " + mt.TableName);

    //generate a sql statment for each table - just grab the first 20
    string sql = String.Format("Select Top 20 * from {0} ", mt.TableName);
    var data = context.ExecuteQuery(mt.RowType.Type, sql);

    //data is here now. Lets print it on the console
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Is there a way to get 10 rows without using Sql string?

for example something similar to this (it gets table associations, I am after 10 (N) rows of table data instead of table associations):

```
var tableData = from t in this.Mapping.GetTables()
                select new 
                {
                    t.TableName,
                    Associations = 
                        from a in t.RowType.Associations
                        select new
                    {
                        a.ThisMember.Name,
                        TypeName = a.ThisMember.Type.Name
                    }
                };
tableData.Dump();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to call `context.GetTable` on the Type:

```
from metaTable in context.Mapping.GetTables()
let table = (IQueryable<object>) context.GetTable (metaTable.RowType.Type)
select table.Take(10)
```

Bear in mind that your examples are relevant to LINQ to SQL, not EF (as the title suggests).

Answer (score -1):

EntityFramework returns IEnumerables when you get data from the database. That means unless you enumerate through it (like get count, ToList(), etc. Lazy loading actually) data will not be fetched from the database.

So here is an example,

```
var database = new SomeDatabase(connectionString);
var tableRows = database.Context.SomeTableName;
var result = new List<SomeDataType>();
var count = 0;
foreach (var tableRow in tableRows)
{

    result.Add(tableRow);
    count++;
    if (count == 10) break;
}
```

Or

```
var result = database.ContextSomeTableName.Take(10).ToList();
```

In this example, only 10 records will be fetched from database.
But if you do this,

```
var tableRows = database.Context.SomeTableName.ToList();
```

You will fetch whole rows from that table (Note ToList()),

Comment: I think this is missing the point as it requires you to know the tablename at compile time. (And it seems to be a complicated way of writing `var result = database.Context.SomeTableName.Take(10).ToList()`)